# Design for tables with the same column value but different names

Tags: database-design

I have the following three tables:

- `doctors (Doc_id, Doc_name)`
- `patient (patient_id, patient_name)`
- `admission (patient_id, sup_Doc, date)`

What is the correct way to go about linking the `doctor` and `admission` tables, given that `sup_Doc` is just a `Doc_id`?

Do I change the name of the `sup_doc` or just link them as is?

I believe this is a theory question.

Comment: Both doctor and patient are admission attributes. So `admission (admission_id, patient_id, doc_id, date, another fields)`.

Comment: What you have may work, and it may not work.  If there can be more than one doctor type on an admission but only one of each type then your schema works, but I'd call the column sup_doc_id so at least taking the prefix off matches the parent table.  If there is only one doctor on an admission then I'd change it to doc_id.  If there can be multiple doctors of a single type (or there is only one type) then you need a joining table that has the columns admission_id, doc_id, and possibly doc_type.